# Remove Password autofill In firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, autofill

In my form I add The autocomeplete="off" and in the inputs either, But Firefox still show the list of entered user, and fill the password field.

I want the name and the password will be blank always.

I try  remove the password after sending, but this is does not work.

Chrome work good, but firefox keep the password.

This is my form code

```
  <form method="POST" class="margin-bottom-0" autocomplete="off" name="loginForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group m-b-20">
                <input type="text" ng-required="true" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="loginData.userName" placeholder="{{holder}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-b-20" ng-show="adminlogin">
                <input type="password" ng-required="adminlogin" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="loginData.password" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
            </div>
            <div class="login-buttons">
                <button ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">LOGIN</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

And in the angular controller:

```
 $scope.loginData = {
        userName: "",
        password: ""
    };

 $scope.login = function () {
        if ($scope.loginForm.$valid) {
            authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {
                $scope.loginData.password = "";            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Use `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)